# PHP constant case

Tags: php

I was wondering if I can set a pre defined parameter value in PHP to lower case instead of upper case as in the example below?

Example 1 - upper case:

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)
```

Example 2 - lower case:

```
imagefilter($im, img_filter_grayscale)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to test if it works, if you are unsure?

Comment: Can I just ask I want a solid answer?

Comment: why don't you take Andre's advice and try it out yourself?

Comment: The best way of learning is by trial and error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A constant is case-sensitive by
> default

see PHP manual: [Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

And why would you want to do this?

Comment: @oneall: By convention, constant identifiers are always uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

constants, like IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE, are case-sensitive in PHP per default (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only achievable if you [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) the wanted lowercase name with the uppercase name, hence that would not be useful and you are/will create duplicated pieces of code, while not necessary..

why would you want to do this anyway ?

Info about PHP constants can be found here [Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)